# How to avoid indirect repurchase of an in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a story book collection app, in which the user is presented with two options when he clicks on a book - 
1) Buy this book for $0.99
2) Buy all 5 books for $4

Let's say a user buys all 5 books for $4, and then uninstalls the application. When the person re-installs it, the purchases have not been restored. So he has the option to buy one books for $0.99 again. So the person has basically unlocked the book that he unlocked in the $4 purchase, again, for $0.99. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: You tell the user to restore in-app purchase of only that item that they have unlocked previously. There is no hey purchase one for $0.99 and then unlock all. Apple treats every in-app purchase as unique if they haven't unlocked it before. Remember, every in-app has it own unique id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [Non-Consumable](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html) which you can simply restore.

So, before you start the buy process of a $0.99 item, you first try to restore the $4 Non-Consumable item. Depending on the success of that restore you known what to do: Either buy the $0.99 item, or set the app state for the $4 purchase.

Of course the $0.99 items should also be Non-Consumables. This means that you also need to try to restore that purchase as well. You could make the restoration process of any purchases part of some sign-in/startup process of the app.